# Best practice for using Balanced API on mobile app

Tags: mobile, payment-gateway, payment, balanced-payments

I am implementing new Balanced API for the payment, and starting to think about putting it on our mobile (native) apps.

I see they have [a javascript library](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/js) for sending credit card information directly to their server. I obviously don't want payment info to go through our server (PCI), and I don't want to include my API key/secret in the app.

So what would be the best way to handle the credit card info on our mobile apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

- For IOS please use the [balanced-ios](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios) library
- For Android please use the [balanced-android](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-android) library

---

Since you're writing for a smartphone you should be able to make a RESTful API call directly to Balanced to tokenize the card without using balanced.js.

The card and bank account endpoints don't require authentication to tokenize these resources so you don't need to worry about including any API keys with the app. The documentation explains how to [tokenize the card](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/api#tokenize-a-credit-card) but let me explain it in more detail:

**TL;DR**

Make a POST directly from your mobile app to the `card_uri` or `bank_account_uri` that is associated with your Marketplace and it will return a response which includes the tokenized resource's URI.

**Example**

If your Marketplace's URI was `/v1/marketplaces/M123-456-7890` then the flow would look like this:

**On the client**

The payload you pass through should look like:

```
{
    "card_number": "5105105105105100",
    "expiration_month": "01",
    "expiration_year": "2020",
    "security_code": "123"
}
```

This should then be submitted like such

```
POST /v1/marketplaces/M123-456-7890/cards
```

The response will look something like:

```
{
  "brand": "visa",
  "name": null, 
  "expiration_year": 2020, 
  "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP991-204-5261/cards/CCfc1596189e0911e18ba9024f5cb9b783", 
  "expiration_month": 12, 
  "state": "new", 
  "last_four": 5100, 
  "address": null
}
```

The client then only needs to return the `uri` of the response to your server, on the server you can associate the card with the user's account.

**On the server**

To associate the card's URI with an existing account you can make a `PUT` request to the account's URI with the URI of the card passed through as a parameter called `card_uri`. If you're creating a new account then `POST` to the marketplaces `accounts_uri` with the email address of the user.

What you want to be careful of is that you don't log the user's `card_number` or `security_code` in any debugging log on the device as this would bring the device into PCI scope and could be bad if their phone was compromised.

Comment: How can we get the "card_uri" or "bank_account_uri" values ? Can you please share some relevant Objective C code?

Comment: Thanks Marshal... Do you know the correct way of adding static Balanced framework in the XCode project?

Comment: @marshall - Is the card URI sensitive information? e.g. Must I send it to my server over https, or can it be sent in the clear via http?

Comment: @Jimbo - it's not sensitive, in order to operate on it someone would need your api key secret.